# CSS page transition silde up

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, transition

I was wondering if there was a simple css/js slide up page transition? I have a website with 3 pages, instead of a navbar I have a button at the bottom that links to the next page but I thought that it might look nicer if the new page slides up on click. The only transitions I can find use pug (which I have no idea how to use)

Thank you

Comment: You can use a library like HighwayJS : https://github.com/Dogstudio/highway/
Do you really need three pages ? Because you could make a one page and on button click you make your transition.

Comment: Try using AOS: https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/